# Python2: how to extract a column from a dssp file and put it in a new file?

Tags: python

I have a very messy problem and I really need your help. I have a lot of dssp files in a folder. Every dssp file contains informations about proteins. Also, I have a separate file containing two columns separated with a colon, containing the IDs of the proteins of the dssp files and their respective chains.

This is how the dssp file look like. [dssp_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf2ex.png)

This is how the IDs and chains file look like. [IDs_and_chains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoTx0.png)

I need two python scripts to extract two columns from a dssp file and putting them into two new files.

In particular, the result that I'm looking for is: from a dssp file, considering the chain of the protein of the ID and chains file (in the dssp is highlighted in blue), I want to create two new files: a fasta file and a new dssp file.

In the fasta file I want ">", the ID of the protein (highlighted in green) and, on one line, all the sequence (highlighted in yellow), like a normal fasta file. In the new dssp file I want ">", the ID of the protein (again, highlighted in green) and, on one line, the structure of the protein (highlighted in orange). For the structures I want to convert everything, to have as a result something like this: 'H':['H','G','I'], 'E':['B','E'], 'C':['T','S','-',''].

This is how the new fasta file should look like.[newfasta_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYTi7.png)

This is how the new dssp file should look like. [newdssp_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao3De.png)

This is what I wrote. I don't know why it gives me a new file but only with the ID and not the structure/sequence that I'm asking for.

```
import sys

dssp = {'H':['H','G','I'],
    'E':['B','E'],
    'C':['T','S','-','']}

def read_dssp_file(filename, chain):
structure = ''.strip()
protein_name = ''
i=0
for line in open(filename):
    if line[0:6].strip() == "HEADER":
        protein_name = line[62:67].strip()
    elif i > 27:
        if chain == line[11:12].strip():
            if line[16:17].strip() in dssp['H']:
                structure += 'H'
            elif line[16:17].strip() in dssp['E']:
                structure += 'E'
            elif line[16:17].strip() in dssp['C']:
                structure += 'C'
    i+=1
return structure, protein_name

def create_dssp_file(data_file):

newfile = open((data_file[1] + ".mdssp").lower(),"w") 

newfile.write(">" + data_file[1] + '\n')   
newfile.write(data_file[0].strip()) 
newfile.close() 

return  newfile

if __name__ == '__main__':
if len(sys.argv)>2:
     file1=sys.argv[1]
     chain=sys.argv[2]
     print create_dssp_file(read_dssp_file(file1, chain))
else:
     print 'Program syntax:\npython', sys.argv[0], 'filenames and chain'
```

This is part of the code for creating the fasta files, instead.

```
def read_dssp_file(filename, chain):
sequence = ''.strip()
protein_name = ''
i=0
for line in open(filename,"r"):
    if line[0:6].strip() == "HEADER":
        protein_name = line[62:67].strip()
    elif i > 26:
        if chain == line[11:12].strip():
            sequence += line[13:14].strip()

    i+=1

return sequence, protein_name
```

Also, as I have to do this for every dssp file that I have in my folder, I don't know how to do it recursively giving the script the whole folder, instead of the single dssp file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the file as text? Does it have to be in python?

Comment: This sounds like a question that would be more appropriate on [bioinformatics.stackexchange.com](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)